# PCB isolation strength VS pad-to-pad distance

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, isolation

Is there any estimation regarding the relation between PCB pad to pad distance and isolation strength?

If the board is covered with the mask and the minimum distance is 2,9 mm which isolation voltage I can expect?

[image]

The red region is the isolated nets.

The age effects (like surface dust) can be skipped in my case as the device will be packed and protected from such particles penetrations.

**EDIT:**

Actually I need 2 kV isolation. But I'd be much more happy to know the science behind the subject - not only estimation that my design *will or will not keep this voltage*. This is why I skipped to specify my actual requirements initially.

**EDIT 2**

After I read the links I've been provided by you I could put the idea in the following form: as I need to withstand 2 kV test (as per my initial requirements) I will redesign the board (if necessary) and then after assembled put it to the test of 2 kV AC voltage applied and than test the insulation resistance which is should be more than 2MOhms @ 500VDC.

So the questions now are:

1. Is the stated above correct? Is this any proper approach?
2. How likely that this PCB as it designed right now on a picture above will pass the test (U2 optocoupler is rated to 3,75 kV RMS). As I stated earlier the minimum distance is 2,9 mm from primary to secondary.

Comment: What is supposed to be isolated from what here, and how much isolation is needed?

Comment: @MattYoung let's say C13 bottom plate to the middle plate of FI1 (the shortest distance I measured). But actually all red-squared nets should be isolated from the others.

Comment: Got that from your edit, but that still doesn't answer how much isolation you need.

Comment: I forget what standard it is, but somewhere I remember reading 40V/mil or 1.6kV/mm. The standard you're testing to matters here.

Comment: @MattYoung the 40V/mil estimation you've specified is for PCB or for just a air gap? Please see my second EDIT for more info.

Comment: I think it was clearance, and clearance is clearance whether it be space between copper on a PCB or air gap. You really need to consult your standard on this.

Comment: @MattYoung actually I think that the **clear** PCB should has better strength as there is a mask. Isn't it?

Comment: No. Solder mask is just that, something to keep solder from going places you don't want it. You should NEVER rely on it from isulation.

Comment: The gap that you require will depend on what the nature of the isolation is and the relevant standard. The rules for safety isolation are different than for functional isolation. So if the breakdown of your insulation results in exposed contacts becoming live then there is a more stringent requirement than is the result is a fuse blowing. As this is a creepage not just a clearance, pollution and moisture are factors too. If the board could be exposed to condensation and dust then the requirement would be higher. Are there any standards e.g. UL? Example, 400V system safety isolation typical 8mm

Comment: It's called creepage distance, maybe this is of any help?

http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/creepage-distance-for-pcbs-handling-line-voltage-ac

It is very hard to give an exact number, because of factors like polution on the pcb or in the air...

Comment: IPC has standards for that sort of thing: http://www.smps.us/pcbtracespacing.html

Comment: If 2kV a transient peak voltage requirement or long term?

Comment: @Rev1.0 I'd test for 2 kVAC for 1 minute (as the standard's requirement). So I'd say it's not a long term.

Comment: I asked, because creepage distance must only be considered for the working voltage (AFAIK). A adequate creepage distance prevents "tracking" (electrical breakdown on the surface of an insulating material). So the limiting factor for the distance in your design is probably the air gap required to prevent 2kV arcing.

Comment: @Rev1.0 As I know from reading above the electrical strength of air gap is about 1.6kV/mm. So 2 mm should be pretty enough for 2 kVAC (=2820 V peak). Right?

Comment: Assuming 2kV is the max pulse withstand voltage you require, you would need 1mm for FUNCTIONAL insulation accoring to EN 60664-1. Just as an example. You may require "basic" or "reinforced insulation". I believe with respect to that EN one would then pick a clearance one level (4kV) or two levels (6kV) higher respectively. That would be 3mm or 5.5mm. But it really depends on the requirements of your design. I am just throwing some numbers at you for reference ;)