# Becoming crazy with EU LVD regulation in PCB and electric strength

Tags: pcb, connector, clearance, creepage

First of all I will explain the design characteristics of my project to make clear what it is and where it enters for regulation.

It is a fixed electric/electronic installation in  offices so it can't be moved and the PCB board size has to be the smallest possible, it has plastic envelopment around all the product and earth and GND are tied (it has an isolated AC/DC power supply), and in theory the electronic's space is waterproof, and the user can't touch anything, it's all Ethernet-controlled.

So my doubts started when I had to implement the normative  EN-60335 about electrical security in home electrodomestics and the IEC 60664 for insulated systems (coated PCBs) which are the ones I assume I have to apply into the design.

The problem comes when I want to use this connector to carry  2 comms wires (serial 485), isolated logic power (+12 V, GND-Earth) and 230 V AC (line-neutral) (I know it shouldn't carry all in the same connector but it was a design requirement :palm:):

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/1723101106/WM11592-ND/5344289

In theory the electric strength of the connector is about 1800 V but some electric test are about 5 kV peaks in the normative, so one of my doubs are about the varistor, at the AC entry, shouldn't it shortcut when the peak tries to pass it and then the connector shouldn't be affected?

In coated boards which is the minimum clearance and creepage between Line, neutral, earth and low voltage lines for this kind of product?

Can the connector and electronics be filled with some kind of plastic isolator to upgrade its isolation capabilities?

Thanks for your time.

I have already posted this in eevblog but I dont know what else to do (ok I can read the normative for four time :) ).

Also I have seen this thread but it didn't solve my questions:

[Creepage distance for PCBs handling line voltage AC?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/creepage-distance-for-pcbs-handling-line-voltage-ac)

Comment: A block diagram of your device would be quite helpful here.

Comment: Separate the three issues breakdown (of solid isolation), clearence/flashover and creepage, since the time constant involved are many orders of magnitude different. That 5 kV peak is via an impedance, so if you have TVRs there, they will limit the voltage as you say. If you successfully have coated the board, everything beneath the coating will now experience polution degree I. Look in the IEC table how much this helps your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks for your time:

-I already solved the issue of clearance, is a minimum of 4 mm for gruop IIIa, Pollution degree 3 and without effective earth(i was told that GND wont have the same diameter as the live wires).

-As for the creepage distance i am taking another look to the normative and that voltage spike should be 3 KV between line and neutral and 2 KV between line and earth.

-What do you mean with the coating? in an isolated environment like this i thought that it was a pollution II type with a coated board.