# How much clearance do I need for a terminal block that will run at 240VAC, 10A max?

Tags: voltage, pcb, ac, relay

To start off, I don't have any experience with designing PCBs for high voltage relays/switches.

I'm currently designing a PCB that has a relay on it that will be used to turn on and off a device (like any typical relay.) This is meant to be a general purpose relay to turn on and off any device.  The maximum expected voltage/current through the relay is going to be 240VAC and 10A. The issue I'm running into is that there isn't a lot of space for clearance on the switching terminals (COM, NO, NC side of the relay) due to the nature of the PCB design.

I have a keep out area around the relay switching terminals and the terminal block connector. From the edge of the through hole pad to the keep out the keep out distance is about 2.2mm.

I wanted to understand if this distance was large enough for creepage and clearance, and if there is anything I need to consider for arc prevention, and if there is anything else I need to be mindful about with the high voltage part of the circuitry.

[image]

Comment: AC voltage will arc approximately 1kV/mm in air. 2.2mm is more than enough to beat back 240VAC, especially on a PCB.

Comment: Does the answer in [Creepage distance for PCBs handling line voltage AC?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/22803/101063) help? Also, what _Pollution Degree_ (measure of external contamination on the PCB) is your product intended for?

Answer (score 2):

IPC-2221 table 6.1 lists a few numbers that will be of interest. In particular is the column B2 for soldered pads to other non-protected copper and, column B4 for tracks under solder resist (permanent polymer coating). The voltage level will be peak Ac in the 301 to 500 volt range: -

[image]

- So, for unprotected copper to unprotected copper (B2) you should have at least 2.5 mm spacing
- For protected copper (permanent polymer coating aka solder resist) you should have at least 0.8 mm spacing

Please also review this table in light of the components that are placed on it (columns A5, A6 and A7). You should also take into account how "polluted" your circuit may become with dust/debris/possible oxidation and environment to ensure you choose safely.

If struggling to meet the limits, consider using cut-outs in the board between tracks.

Comment: What is considered "protected copper"? Copper with epoxy, solder mask, or anything that keeps it from being exposed?

Comment: @J.Street I've clarified that in my answer and, it can certainly include epoxy coating.

Comment: As you mention the pollution degree: For which pollution degree is the present table applicable?

Comment: I didn't mention "pollution degree"; I said "You should also take into account how "polluted" your circuit may become with dust/debris/possible oxidation and environment to ensure you choose safely"

Comment: How cut outs between tracks could help?

Comment: It radically opens up the surface-**creepage**-gap into being an air-**clearance**-gap and, air-gaps don't collect dust and, have massively greater dielectric strength compared to the surface of a PCB @Fredled

Answer (score 0):

You have the IPC rules, however these assume your board is clean.
It may not remain clean, or not be as clean after soldering.

Based on experience we use the following drc rules:

- Masked traces 2.5mm
- Bare traces 5.0mm

This means that you need at least 7.5mm pitch connectors if you want >5mm between the annular rings of the through hole pads.

Also note that mains is up to +30% short term and has EFT requirements.
EFT (Electrical Fast Transient) is especially relevant if you are switching inductive loads with the relay.